# Avoid duplicates on import of updated excel-sheets. Unique-Index can only hold 10 fields max

Tags: sql, ms-access, indexing, duplicates, unique

I am facing the following situation:

I import an Excel-Sheet, then some columns are modified (e.g. "comments")
After a while, I would receive an updated Excel-Sheet containing the records from the old Excel-sheet as well as new ones.
I do not want to import the records that already exist in the database.

Step-by-Step:

Initial Excel-sheet

```
col1  col2  comments
A        A       
A        B
```

After import, some fields will get manipulated

```
col1  col2       comments
A        A       looks good
A        B       fine with me
```

Then I receive an excel sheet with updates

```
col1  col2  comments
A        A       
A        B
A        C
```

After this update-step, the database should look like

```
col1  col2       comments
A        A       looks good
A        B       fine with me
A        C
```

I was planning to simply create a  unique index on all fields that won't get manipulated, so only the new records will get imported. (sth like

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD CONSRAINT unique_key UNIQUE (col1,col2)
```

My problem now is that Access somehow only allows composite indices of max. 10 fields. My tables all have around 11-20 cols...

I could maybe import the updated xls to a temp. table, and do s.th like

```
INSERT INTO tbl_old SELECT col1,col2, "" FROM tbl_new WHERE (col1,col2) NOT IN (SELECT col1,col2 FROM tbl_old UNION SELECT col1,col2 FROM tbl_new)
```

But I'm wondering if there isn't a more straigt-forward way...

Any ideas how I can solve that?

Comment: You may want to investigate to see if you can use the SQL merge command with your version of Access.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ... man, you must get tired of retagging those *access* tags, especially as its first line is *DON'T USE THIS TAG FOR MS ACCESS*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [EXISTS](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/exists.php) condition:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_old (col1, col2, comments)
SELECT col1, col2, Null 
FROM tbl_new
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT col1, col2 FROM tbl_old WHERE tbl_old.col1 = tbl_new.col1 AND tbl_old.col2 = tbl_new.col2);
```

Comment: Looks good, but there will be a problem if one field of one record is null, e.g. first record in both old and new table would be `A / null / anything`.
As `null = null` is always false, this will create a duplicate

Comment: So it would be 
`WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT col1, col2 FROM tbl_old WHERE (tbl_old.col1 = tbl_new.col1 OR (tbl_old.col1 IS NULL AND tbl_new.col1 IS NULL)) AND (tbl_old.col2 = tbl_new.col2 OR (tbl_old.col2 IS NULL AND tbl_new.col2 IS NULL))`

Comment: Yes that is correct. I would also wrap the entire WHERE condition in parentheses: `((tbl_old.col1 = tbl_new.col1 OR (tbl_old.col1 IS NULL AND tbl_new.col1 IS NULL)) AND (tbl_old.col2 = tbl_new.col2 OR (tbl_old.col2 IS NULL AND tbl_new.col2 IS NULL)))`

Answer (score 0):

Considering you will use SQL approach:

```
INSERT INTO table_old (col1, col2)
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table_new
EXCEPT
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table_old
```

:)

It will insert `null` in `comments` column though. Use this:

```
INSERT INTO table_old 
SELECT * FROM table_new
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM table_old
```

to avoid null values. Also both tables have to have the same amount of columns. For Oracle go with `minus` instead of `except`. Equivalent SQL query would be made with `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

```
INSERT INTO table_old (col1 , col2)
    SELECT N.col1, N.col2
    FROM   table_new N
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table_old O ON O.col2 = N.col2
    WHERE O.col2 IS NULL
```

Which will also provide `null` values to `comments` column, as we are inserting only col1 and col2. All inserts tested on provided table examples.

I would just put PK `ID` column in those tables.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `LEFT OUTER JOIN table_old O ON O.col1=N.col1 AND O.col2 = N.col2`
And I don't get the reason for what you're using the condition `WHERE O.col2 IS NULL`

Comment: @RobertL. actually, it should. Look in my edits. I wanted to go with something shorter, and it works on your examples.

For real, this should go like:
`INSERT INTO table_old (col1 , col2)
    SELECT N.col1, N.col2
    FROM   table_new N
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table_old O ON O.col1 = N.col1 AND O.col2 = N.col2
    WHERE O.col2 IS NULL OR O.col1 IS NULL`

Comment: @RobertL. Reason for `WHERE` clause is that `LEFT OUTER JOIN` gets all rows from the table on the left (here table_new) and from the table on the right (table_old) _only_ those rows, which appear on the left too, which results in all rows from table_new. So, now we want the opposite, we want rows for which table_old has returned null.

Comment: @RobertL. simply, if values exist in table_new, but not in table_old, then table_old will insert `NULL` in `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in specified columns (col1 or col2), and we want exactly that information.

Comment: @RobertL. as I said, this is only an equivalent for `EXCEPT` keyword. Kostas K. answer is also completly correct. Choose whatever suits you best.